# Explicitly change the context of User while scheduling a batch

Tags: batch, salesforce-id, schedulebatch, triggercontext

I have a requirement where I schedule a batch to run via trigger on insert and update event. However, the batch schedules in the context of the User who makes the changes. Because of which the LastModifiedBy field changes in the name of that user. This is a standard feature.

***My requirement is to find out a way via which I should be explicitly able to schedule the batch in the context of a specific user, irrespective of who updates/inserts the record and irrespective of who is currently logged in. 
Is there a way to do it?***

Thanks,
Smriti

Answer (score 2):

There is no possible way by which current user context can be changed. However following solution can be opted if it fits your use case:

1. Remove batch execution call from trigger.
2. Prepare a schedule apex class that calls your batch execution.
3. Schedule your Schedule apex to run after the frequency of some interval (Say one hour).
4. Scheduling should be done by user to whom you want to make changes on records. Same will appear in last modified by field.
5. Schedule job will check if some records are available to process. if yes call batch class else exit.

I hope that helps.

Scheduling  Code to be run as user who should be context user for operations:

```
// Run job every hour at 00 minutes
String cron1 ='0 0 * * * ?';
ScheduleClass sc=new ScheduleClass ();
system.schedule('Job 1', sc, cron1);

// Run job every hour at 15 minutes
String cron2 ='0 15 * * * ?';    
system.schedule('Job 2', sc, cron2);

// Run job every hour at 30 minutes
String cron3 ='0 30 * * * ?';   
system.schedule('Job 3', sc, cron3);  

 // Run job every hour at 45 minutes
    String cron4 ='0 45 * * * ?';    
    system.schedule('Job 3', sc, cron4);
```

Please note that code above will add 4 jobs every hour running at a frequency of 15 minutes. You can increase the job count to 12 to achieve frequency of 5 minutes but make sure you have proper exception handling. Like what if next job time has arrived but previous not yet finished. Such scenario may result in data issues. Take frequency decision wisely as you are using your daily Asynchronous apex limit as well.

Comment: Hi @Mukesh, I am scheduling the batch via scheduler, but it has to be done via trigger. Say 5 minutes after the trigger fires. So probably this solution won't fit in my use case.

Comment: You can put multiple jobs say at 00, 15, 30, 45 minutes of hour. Eventually code running after a frequency of 15 minutes. More jobs would be required to decrease frequency to 5 minutes.

Comment: Yes, thats correct.  I do understand that but the requirement says it to be at an interval of 5 min. That too in context of some other User who hasn't updated/inserted records.

Comment: @Smriti that can be achieved. I have done it once for some requirement.

Comment: Oh great, can you please share the approach and code snippet here.

Comment: @SmritiKumari Revised answer. Do have a look.

Comment: Sorry @Mukesh, but this is not what I am looking for. Please reconsider :My requirement is to find out a way via which I should be explicitly able to schedule the batch in the context of a specific user, irrespective of who updates/inserts the record and irrespective of who is currently logged in. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40268/discussion-between-mukesh-verma-and-smriti-kumari).